# Finding the hidden text in xpath Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I wish I could get the text below but what I got is ''.

Any tips to go further? This is my code and the following is from the source page.

```
x = element.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="detailsContent"]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span[3]')[0].text
<span class="text-sm md:text-base text-primary cursor-pointer hover:underline" onclick="$(this).swapWithNext();gaTrack('Interact', 'MoreDetails-Show', 'NAICS Code', 1, true);">show</span>
<span class="text-sm md:text-base hidden">332992, Small Arms Ammunition Manufacturing</span>
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to the page or the full src (html) for the page? If not, it's impossible to rule out why either: 

A.which part of your xpath isn't working properly, 
or 
B. The text you're trying to scrape isn't grabbed by the default `.text` attribute (I don't think this is the issue). Additionally, you may want to try the find by class method instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer please

Answer (score 1):

*To get the text, try using `get_attribute("innerHTML")`*

*Example*

```
x = element.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="detailsContent"]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span[3]'
).get_attribute("innerHTML")
```